# Getting materials' and textures' names in Python

Tags: python, blender

I'd like to print all materials' and it's textures' names with this script:

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.type == "MESH":
        for mat_slot in ob.material_slots:
            if mat_slot.material:
                if mat_slot.material.node_tree:
                   print("material:" + str(mat_slot.material.node_tree.name))
                   for x in mat_slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
                        if x.type=='TEX_IMAGE':
                           print(" texture: "+str(x.name))
```

But the output is just general names like this:

```
material:Shader Nodetree
 texture: Image Texture
material:Shader Nodetree
 texture: Image Texture
material:Shader Nodetree
 texture: Image Texture
```

So, how can I get the textures' file names like '`pic.png`'?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out:

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.type == "MESH":
        for mat_slot in ob.material_slots:
            if mat_slot.material:
                if mat_slot.material.node_tree:
                   print("material:" + str(mat_slot.material.name))                
                   for x in mat_slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
                        if x.type=='TEX_IMAGE':
                           print(" texture: "+str(x.image.name))
```

This prints:

```
material:metal
 texture: metal.png
material:coppercoil
 texture: coil.png
material:steel
 texture: steel.png
```